# classifying the records into different groups based on dates using Teradata

Tags: sql, grouping, teradata, row-number

I have the following data with their `MIN`,  `MAX` and `CLOSE` dates.

All I am trying to classify these accounts into three groups based on these dates and show the count for each month they are active

Have

```
  custID         MINDate     MAXDATE         CLOSEDATE
  10001          1/1/2022   12/31/2022
  20001          7/6/2022   12/31/2022
  30001          4/5/20022  6/10/2022         6/10/2022
  40001          1/1/2022   12/31/2022
```

Grp1 - If the `custID is available entire 2022 then it would be shown under all the 12 months

Grp2 - If the 'CustID is available only for a few days then it would be in 'Grp2 only for that particular month and for the remaining months it would be in 'Grp1

Grp3 - If 'CustId is populated with 'CLOSEDATE then it would be `Grp3 for that closed month

Want

```
           jan22 Feb22 Mar22 Apr22 May22 Jun22 Jul22 Aug22 Sep22 Oct22 Nov22 Dec22       
Grp1         2    2     2      2     3      2    2      3    3     3    3     3   
Grp2                           1                 1    
Grp3                                        1
```

10001  - Y across all the months  Grp1

20001  - Y in July Grp2, Y from August - December

30001  - Y in April Grp2, Y in May Grp1 and Y in Jun Grp3

40001  - Y across all the months  Grp1

I tried to build the following logic but lost in the middle

```
    WITH cte1 AS (
      SELECT custID,
        MINDate,
        MAXDATE,
        ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(MINDate, 'MM'), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custID ORDER BY MINDate) - 1) AS Month
      FROM Have
      QUALIFY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM MINDate) = EXTRACT(MONTH FROM ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(MINDate, 'MM'), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY custID ORDER BY MINDate) - 1))
    ), cte2 AS (
      SELECT custID,
        Month,
        CASE WHEN Month = ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(MAXDATE, 'MM'), 1) THEN LAST_DAY(MAXDATE) - MAXDATE + 1 ELSE 1 END AS Days
      FROM (
        SELECT custID,
          MIN(Month) AS Month,
          MAX(MAXDATE) AS MAXDATE
        FROM cte1
        GROUP BY custID
      ) t1
      INNER JOIN cte1 t2 ON t1.custID = t2.custID AND t1.Month <= t2.Month AND t2.Month < ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(MAXDATE, 'MM'), 1)
    ), 
      SELECT Month, SUM(Days) AS Days
      FROM cte2
      GROUP BY Month
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I would solve this:

1. Join to `sys_calendar.calendar` to get all dates between the `MINDATE` and `MAXDATE`. Filter for just the dates that occur on the 1st of the month for each `sys_calendar.calendar.calendar_date`. This way we have a record for every `custid`/`month_start` combination.

   <sup>(You could also use Teradata's `EXPAND ON` clause so you don't have to go to `sys_calendar` table and deal with that join, but `EXPAND ON` is not compatible with `PIVOT` in the same sql submission)</sup>
2. Using a CASE expression determine, for each of those records, in which group they belong using the logic you outlined.
3. Pivot.

This will look like:

<sup>Updated to incorporate dnoeth's improvements</sup>

```
WITH expanded_months AS 
(
    SELECT Have.*, calendar_date as month_start
    FROM Have 
        INNER JOIN sys_calendar.calendar cal 
            ON PERIOD(TRUNC(MINDATE, 'MM'), NEXT(MAXDATE)) CONTAINS cal.calendar_date
    WHERE cal.day_of_month = 1
)
, month_groups AS 
(
SELECT em.*, COUNT(month_start) OVER (PARTITION BY custID) as month_count,
    CASE 
         WHEN month_count < 12 AND month_start = TRUNC(CLOSEDATE, 'MM') THEN 'Grp3'
         WHEN month_count < 12 AND LAG(month_start) OVER (PARTITION BY custid ORDER BY month_start) IS NULL THEN 'Grp2'
         ELSE 'Grp1'
         END as Grp
FROM expanded_months em
)
SELECT pvt.*
FROM (SELECT Grp, month_start FROM month_groups) mg
PIVOT (
      count(*) as val
      FOR month_start 
      IN (
            DATE '2022-01-01' AS jan22,
            DATE '2022-02-01' AS feb22,
            DATE '2022-03-01' AS mar22,
            DATE '2022-04-01' AS apr22,
            DATE '2022-05-01' AS may22,
            DATE '2022-06-01' AS jun22,
            DATE '2022-07-01' AS jul22,
            DATE '2022-08-01' AS aug22,
            DATE '2022-09-01' AS sep22,
            DATE '2022-10-01' AS oct22,
            DATE '2022-11-01' AS nov22,
            DATE '2022-12-01' AS dec22
        )     
      )pvt
ORDER BY Grp
```

---

| Grp | jan22_val | feb22_val | mar22_val | apr22_val | may22_val | jun22_val | jul22_val | aug22_val | sep22_val | oct22_val | nov22_val | dec22_val |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Grp1 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 | 3 |
| Grp2 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| Grp3 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Comment: I can't imaging a reason why EXPAND ON and PIVOT can't be used together, this is a crazy restriction

Comment: Great solution :-) Two simplifications: first of month calculation -> `Trunc`, and the initial calendar join can be done using ANCHOR PERIOD logic: `SELECT  
  Have.*, Trunc(MINDATE, 'MM') AS month_start
FROM Have 
    INNER JOIN sys_calendar.calendar cal 
        ON PERIOD(month_start, NEXT(MAXDATE)) CONTAINS cal.calendar_date
WHERE EXTRACT(DAY FROM calendar_date) = 1`

Comment: @dnoeth I wrote this using EXPAND ON just because it seemed like a quick way of dealing with the problem but ran into `[Error 4306] [SQLState HY000] Invalid PIVOT query: Pivot query is not supported with EXPAND clause.` I didn't bother with trying to find a band-aid for it and just went to the `sys_calendar` as a next-best option.

Comment: I'll change over to Trunc and the really great idea to filter `calendar` for the first. When I wrote that sys_calendar bit in, I flagged it mentally that I needed to refactor since it felt heavy handed, but then didn't bother going back.

Comment: Thanks @JNevill. If I use this query for my ~30mm records, I am getting CPU time error. Is there a way to optimize this query

Comment: If you want data for a specific year 2022 you can add a `AND calendar_date BETWEEN DATE '2022-01-01' AND DATE '2022-12-31'` to reduce the dates in the product join from 201*12 to 12

Comment: You could consider writing the CTE result sets out to a volatile table to break up the execution into chunks to get under your CPU limit. Besides that, it's likely just a data volume issue since there is a lot of logic needed to get from your raw data to this pivotted/grouped results.